# Blocked host: localhost ruby on rails 6.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, ruby-on-rails-6

I am developing my first rails 6 app but when I try to serve it in development environment behind my nginx server, I find this message

[image: Blocked host: localhost]

I tried adding the configuration mentioned in the error in `config/environments/development.rb` and in `config/application.rb` but it didn't work.

I am using rails 6.0.0, ruby 2.6.5, nginx 1.10.3

If I go to http://localhost:3000 (the puma URL directly) it works fine. But I want to know why I am getting this error.

Answer (score 3):

Host Authorization is added because of `DNS rebinding attacks` here are more details about and also link to more detailed explanation.

> Introduce ActionDispatch::HostAuthorization Host Authorization is a
>   new middleware that guards against `DNS rebinding attacks` by explicitly
>   permitting the hosts a request can be sent to. More information about
>   the attack itself is available in this Medium post and in [Daniel
>   Miessler’s DNS Rebinding attack explained](https://danielmiessler.com/blog/dns-rebinding-explained/). By default it’s set for all
>   Rails 6 applications and allows in development the following hosts
>   IPAddr.new(“0.0.0.0/0”), IPAddr.new(“::/0”), “localhost”] it supports
>   arrays of RegExp, Proc, IPAddr and String or a single String in the
>   configuration. What this means is that with Rails 6, we will need to
>   explicitly set our domains in the environments configuration files.
>   More information is available at the HostAuthoriation code and
>   HostAuthorization tests.

Comment: There is no config folder inside app folder, but I understand what you tried to say, I already edited my question because I have had tried adding it to config/environments/development.rb

Comment: did you check this explanation? https://www.fngtps.com/2019/rails6-blocked-host/

Comment: Yes, I read that, but it says localhost is enabled by default, so I think there is a bug somewhere, but, what do I know?
I also don't want to disable host checking, I just want to know what's going on
Thank you

Comment: Here is also question about: https://github.com/thoughtbot/suspenders/issues/975  and also rails config.hosts implementation: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/528c5bb224a2f9ea6eee7b15ef5de5e9d17bf309/railties/lib/rails/application/default_middleware_stack.rb#L16 so you can check it bit more maybe you can find some logic.

Answer (score 3):

It was an issue on [Rails side](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/43864).

Upgrade to `6.0.4.4` or `6.1.4.4` like you can read in their [blog post](https://rubyonrails.org/2021/12/15/Rails-6-0-4-4-and-6-1-4-4-have-been-released).